# Multi-master for high availability on CapRover?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am setting up an application using CapRover (moving from just a single ec2 instance after a hardware failure knocked the whole thing offline). I have everything containerized in Docker, it's all stateless so I don't need persistent storage, and it's just about ready to go. However, I'm discovering that while CapRover can obviously scale the application easily by adding as many worker nodes as necessary, there is still only one master node that serves as the load balancer. But if that node goes down, the whole service goes offline. So it is no better than what I had before with the single ec2 instance. Am I missing something? Is there a way to set up CapRover so this single point of failure is eliminated?

For this application (small web app with not a lot of traffic) I feel like kubernetes is overkill. I just want high availability and no single points of failure. Any suggestions?

Comment: It's difficult to save. What is your application, what does it do? What is CapRover? I've never heard of it. K8s is overkill for most things, I've used ECS for enterprise container hosting that has to work 24/7/365.